# Is an isolated singularity of a complex-valued function an isolated point of the domain of the function?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb C$ be open and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb C$. We say that $z_0\in\mathbb C$ is an *isolated singularity* of $f$ if $f$ is holomorphic on a punctured neighborhood $N$ of $z_0$.

On the other hand, there is the following paragraph in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity) of this notion:

> *Formally, and within the general scope of functional analysis, an isolated singularity for a function $f$ is any topologically isolated point within an open set where the function is defined.*

I don't get this. In a general topological space $E$, we say that $x\in E$ is an *isolated point* of $B\subseteq E$ if there is an open subset $U\subseteq E$ with $B\cap U=\{x\}$.

But why is $z_0$ an isolated point of $N$?

Comment: That point is isolated in the set of points where $f$ is singular

Comment: @ACheca How do you define "singular"?

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't have the best written article, it seems. Consult Conway's book or Ahlfors' book on Complex Analysis for rigorous definitions of singularities and isolated singularities. I am not really getting the given definition very cleanly : a singularity should be a point at which $f$ should not be definable, but here $z_0 \in \Omega$ is very much possible.

Comment: As a general rule, if you are just learning a basic math subject, do not use Wikipedia as your main reference, pick up a textbook and start reading. While some Wikipedia math articles are quite good, other are just plain wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, one should remember that **anybody** can edit a Wikipedia page, regardless of their qualification. In this case, by looking through the history of edits, this particular offending sentence (or, rather, some version of it) was initially written by an engineer, who clearly did not understand the definition; then another engineer tried to correct it but made it even worse. The correct sentence should be something like:

"In the language of topology, an isolated singularity of $f$ is an [isolated point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point) of the set $\partial \Omega$."

or

"In the language of topology, an isolated singularity of $f$ is an [isolated point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point) of the set ${\mathbb C}\setminus \Omega$."

(There is some disagreement if $\infty$ is allowed as an isolated singularity; if it is, then $\partial \Omega$ is understood as the boundary of $\Omega$ in the Riemann sphere.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Meanwhile I was able to show that if $\tau$ is the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb C$, $\Omega\in\tau$, $f:\Omega\to X$ ($X$ being any normed space) is holomorphic and $S:=\{z_0\in\mathbb C\setminus\Omega:z_0\text{ is an isolated singularity of }f\}$, then every point in $S$ is an $\tau$-isolated point of $S$ (which implies that it is a $\tau$-isolated point of $\mathbb C\setminus\Omega$) and hence $S$ is $\tau$-discrete. Moreover, $S$ is $\left.\tau\right|_{\Omega\cup S}$-closed, which is almost trivial, since $\Omega$ and $S$ are disjoint. Do you agree?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Sure, I would just remove the word "almost."

Answer (score 0):

Do remember that anyone can do any changes in wikipedia so don't completely rely on wikipedia.

An isolated singularity of f is an isolated point of the set ∂Ω.